# Bracket IDE's Quick Markup equivalent for VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, markup, adobe-brackets

**Quick Markup** (https://github.com/redmunds/brackets-quick-markup) is an extension available for **Brackets IDE** for HTML development. The extension can be activated with a shortcut *Ctrl+Alt+M*. When it is active, we can use custom shortcuts to insert custom HTML tags instead of typing them. For example, to make insert `<b></b>` tags around a word, we just need to select the word and hit *Ctrl+B*. The shortcuts and their corresponding tags can be customized.

I'm looking for a similar extension or feature like this in Visual Studio Code. I tried searching but couldn't find anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

`keybindings.json`

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation",
    "when": "editorHasSelection",
    "args": {
        "abbreviation": "b"
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+b",
    "command": "editor.emmet.action.wrapWithAbbreviation",
    "when": "editorHasSelection",
    "args": {
        "abbreviation": "pre>code"
    }
},
```

You can also call it without `args` and just type the tags every time.

---

Or just typing anything:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "<br />"
    }
}
```